# Hamilton-Jacobi Equation: Why does any $F(q,Q,0)=f(q,Q)$ lead to a solution?

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, differential-equations

I) Given the Hamilton-Jacobi equation,$$\frac{\partial F(q,Q,t)}{\partial t}+H\left(q,\frac{\partial F(q,Q,t)}{\partial q},t\right)=0 $$
it is stated that any function $$F(q,Q,t=0)=f(q,Q)\tag{22}$$ would generate a solution to the problem. How does that work?

My question arose after reading the document [The Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/mathur.16/821hj.pdf) 
on page 4, equation 22 — this might help to understand my question.

I have little knowledge of PDE's, so I don't know if this is some general property of PDE's or if there is some other reason for it.

Is the argument that I can for example numerically integrate the function from this point using the HJ equation to obtain $F(q,Q,t)$ at all other times?

II) I tried to solve the free particle and realised there are some points that are unclear. Given is
$$
H=\frac{p^2}{2m}.
$$
Let 
$$
F(q,Q,t)=W(q,Q)-Qt
$$
and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}=p$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Q}=P$. The Hamilton-Jacobi equation is 
$$
H(q,\frac{\partial F}{\partial q},t) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = 0.
$$

This reduces to 
$$
\frac{1}{2m}\left( \frac{\partial W}{\partial q} \right)^2 = Q.
$$
Solving for $W(q,Q)$ by integration over $\int^q_{q_0}dq'$ after rearrangement yields
$$W(q,Q) = \sqrt{2mQ}(q-q_0) + W(q_0, Q).
$$
Now we can write down $F$:
$$
F(q,Q,t)=\sqrt{2mQ}(q-q_0) + W(q_0, Q) - Qt.
$$

Is this not the general solution for the principal function? Is there still some sort of constant or function which I could add or remove from this solution?

Comment: Are you asking for a proof of existence of $F$-solutions to the HJ eq?

Comment: I am asking why giving $F(q,Q,t=0)=f(q,Q)$ leads to a solution.  I also read the statement that the general solution depends due to initial conditions on an arbitrary function $f(q,Q)$. I don't understand why i can pick any function $f(q,Q)$ as initial condition for a solution. Why is that true ?

Comment: A differential equation does not give a unique solution unless we specify initial conditions. Think of $\dot{x}(t) = c$ gives $x(t) = t  c + b$. $b$ is an absolutely arbitrary constant that can be fixed by imposing a specific value for the initial condition $x(t=0) = b =2$ for example.

Comment: As other people have pointed out, $F$ is not an initial condition. $F$ is the generator of the canonical transformamation $p=\partial F/\partial q$. This reduces the $2$nd differential equation to one which is $1$st order in $F$. If the Hamiltonian was independent of $t$, then $F=F_{0}-Et$.

Comment: Can someone perhaps give an example ? Simply use a free moving particle and show what $f(q,Q)$ could be ? I don't see how it fits in.

Comment: Hi Hans Wurst: Note that you so far (v3) only solved the 1D free case where the HJ eq becomes an ODE.

Comment: I am well aware that the HJ-equation leads to a nonlinear pde for the function F in general and that this is a special case where H is fully separable and independent of time. But i am not sure what kind of solution we obtain in the end. Is the principal function the general solution or just a particular solution to the nonlinear pde obtained by the HJ-equation ?  Can we even determine the principal function in general form from the HJ-equation or is it impossible ? In my example it looks to me that i obtained the general solution. I need to ask since i dont know differential equation's well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I) We can rewrite the [HJE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) 
$$\frac{\partial F(q,Q,t)}{\partial t}~=~-H\left(q,\frac{\partial F(q,Q,t)}{\partial q},t\right)$$
with a [type 1 generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_1_generating_function) $F(q,Q,t)$ into a fixed-point integral equation  $$F(q,Q,t_f)~=~F(q,Q,t_i)-\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt~H(q, \frac{\partial F(q,Q,t)}{\partial q},  t).$$ Given an arbitrary initial profile $$F(q,Q,t_i)~=~f(q,Q)\tag{22}$$ we can in principle find a unique local solution $F(q,Q,t)$  to the HJE, cf. the general mathematical theory for [1st-order non-linear PDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Fully_nonlinear_case) [2,3].

II) OP considers a free 1D particle, and lists a complete solution of type 1. Similarly, a complete solution to [Hamilton's principal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) (which is a [type 2 generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function)) is 
$$S(x,t; \alpha_1, \alpha_2)~=~\alpha_1 x - \frac{\alpha_1^2}{2m}t +\alpha_2. $$  Note however that a [complete solution to a PDE is *not* a general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation#General_solution_and_complete_integral) [4,5], despite its name!

References:

1. [S. Mathur](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/mathur.16/courses.html), [*Hamilton-Jacobi equation*](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/mathur.16/821hj.pdf); p. 4 eq. (22).
2. R.L. Bryant, S. S. Chern, R.B. Gardner, H.L. Goldschmidt & P.A. Griffiths, *Exterior Differential Systems,* 2011; p. 30-35.
3. Y. Choquet-Bruhat, C. DeWitt-Morette, Cécile de Witt & M. Dillard-Bleick, *Analysis, Manifolds and Physics, Part 1: Basics,* 1982; p. 242-258.
4. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Section 10.1 first footnote.
5. L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *Mechanics,* vol. 1 (1976); $\S$47 footnote on p. 148.